# Не передается текст из QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Есть две формы :

- 1 - основная
- 2 - диалог

В главной есть `QTextEdit`. Во второй форме есть переменная `text`. Когда я пытаюсь этой переменной текст из `TextEdit` передается пустая строка.

Почему ?

Фрагмент кода :

```
class DApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, TextEditorDes.Ui_Form ) :
  def __init__(self) :
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.MainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
    self.MainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 581, 411)) 


    self.Dialog = Dialog(self)


    self.DialogButton.clicked.connect(self.DialogFunc)
  def DialogFunc() :
      self.Dialog.show()

 class Dialog(QWidget, DialogDes.Ui_Form) :
  def __init__(self, parent) :
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.parent = parent
    self.text = self.parent.MainTextEdit.toPlainText()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы прописали `self.text = self.parent.mainTextEdit.toPlainText()`
в методе `__init__` , которая выполняется **ОДИН** раз и на момент инициализации
в `mainTextEdit` пустой.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):      #, DialogDes.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent

    def printText(self):                                                # +++
        self.text = self.parent.mainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        print("1", self.text)


class DApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    #, TextEditorDes.Ui_Form ):
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.mainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)                    # - Form / + self
        self.mainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 581, 411)) 

        self.dialogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("dialogButton", self)
        self.dialogButton.clicked.connect(self.dialogFunc)

        self.dialog = Dialog(self)

    def dialogFunc(self):                                                # + self     
        self.dialog.show()
        self.dialog.printText()                                          # +++
        print("2", self.dialog.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DApp()
    w.resize(600, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]